# PostgreSQL Peer authentication failed when using Ansible to create a database user

Tags: postgresql, authentication, ansible, devops

I'm trying to use Ansible to create a PostgreSQL database user, but I'm encountering the following error:

> TASK [Create db user] **********************************************************************  fatal: [test]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres""}

````
Here is my Ansible playbook:


```yaml
---
- name: postgresql demo
  hosts: all
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  vars:
    db_user: myuser
    db_password: MySecretPassword123

  tasks:
    - name: Utility present
      ansible.builtin.package:
        name: python3-psycopg2
        state: present

    - name: Create db user
      community.postgresql.postgresql_user:
        state: present
        name: "{{ db_user }}"
        password: "{{ db_password }}"
````

I've tried various solutions, including changing the `become_user`, but the issue persists. How can I resolve the "Peer authentication failed" error when using Ansible to create a PostgreSQL user?

Comment: [Peer auth](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-peer.html) is based on the OS user not the Postgres user, where the OS name of the user connecting has to match that of a Postgres user name. Though per the link you can create a mapping to alias an OS user name to a Postgres user name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the operating system user is that Ansible is running under; let's call it `ansible`. Peer authentication fails because the name of the operating system user is different from the name of the database user.

You can work around that by specifying a mapping. In `pg_hba.conf` change the `peer` line to

```
# TYPE  DATABASE      USER        ADDRESS       METHOD
local   all           all                       peer map=foransible
```

Then add the following to `pg_ident.conf`:

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
foransible      ansible                 postgres
foransible      postgres                postgres
```

Don't forget to reload PostgreSQL after changing the files. Then operating system user `ansible` can connect as database user `postgres`.

Answer (score -2):

The ***Peer authentication failed problem*** frequently happens because PostgreSQL by default use the ***peer*** authentication technique for local connections. In order to use this technique, a PostgreSQL username must match the operating system username. PostgreSQL makes an attempt to authenticate you as the ***postgres*** user when you perform tasks as that user in your Ansible playbook, which results in the error.

You can either alter the authentication process or explicitly specify a host for the connection in order to fix this. If you decide to specify a host, making it ***localhost*** requires Ansible to use TCP/IP rather than the Unix domain socket to connect to PostgreSQL, thereby disabling the ***Peer authentication*** technique. As demonstrated in the previous response, you may accomplish this by include the `PGHOST` environment variable in your Ansible task. Another option is to change the `pg_hba.conf` file in PostgreSQL to allow ***peer*** authentication for the ***postgres*** user without a password. However, exercise caution while making changes to the `pg_hba.conf` file since they may affect the security of your PostgreSQL system.

Comment: Smacks of AI babble.

Comment: I love the ending "exercise caution". What human being actually says that, really?